# Acrobat Pro - Change Price Based on Date

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I can't figure out how to do a simple price change of something in an Acrobat Pro PDF Form based on the current date... Here's what I'm trying to do in English:

The current early bird price for the conference is $775.  On May 10th the price will then increase to $875.

My main problem is I'm not sure how to reference the date as a number so that my function can be "greater than" (or after) the date

Here's what I have so far:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var price = 775;

if( currentDate > "May 10 2016") price.value = 875;
```

Does anyone know how to do a number calculation based on the date, or should I be doing this another way?

Comment: I eventually figured it out.  Instead of using a script outside of the checkbox, I set the checkbox to activate the following script when clicked.  I set the checkbox export value to "On" and now when it's clicked the script updates the price with the appropriate amount.
Here it is:

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.  I moved the script to inside the checkbox, and set the checkbox to run the script rather than export a value, and set the checkbox export value to "On". Now when it's clicked the script updates the price with the appropriate amount.
The last bit of code just clears the price value when the checkbox is turned off.
Here's the script if anyone is interested:

```
var today = new Date;
var futureDate = Date.parse("May 14, 2016");
if (today.getTime() > futureDate && this.getField("1AttendAll").value == "On"){this.getField("1AttendTotal").value = 875;}

else if (today.getTime() < futureDate && this.getField("1AttendAll").value == "On"){this.getField("1AttendTotal").value = 775;
this.getField("EarlyBirdText").value = "Early Registration Discount Applied";}

else {
this.getField("1AttendTotal").value = 0;
this.getField("EarlyBirdText").value = "";
```

Comment: What is the exact script you have added to the checkbox? To which event/action did you add the script? What is the meaning when the box is checked/unchecked?